# How to create multilevel dictionary from a file using python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a multilevel dictionary from a file.

The file format is like bellow: file.txt

```
name1   gene1   cds     1       2       +
name1   gene1   cds     2       5       -
name1   gene1   exon    1       2       +
name1   gene1   exon    2       5       -
name1   gene2   cds     4       6       +
name1   gene2   cds     6       9       +
name1   gene2   exon    1       10      +
name1   gene2   exon    2       5       -
name2   gene1   gene    1000    1333    +
```

Dictionary data structure is like bellow.

```
dct =  { 'name1' : {'gene1':{'cds':[[1, 2, '+'],[2, 5, '-']], "exon": [[1, 2, '+'],[2, 5, '-']] } , 'gene2':{'cds':[[4, 6, '+'],[6, 9, '+']], "exon": [[1, 10, '+'],[2, 5, '-']] } } }
```

or simply for understanding:

```
name1
        gene1
                exon
                        1, 2, "+",
                        2, 5, "-"
                CDS
                        1, 2, "+"
                        2, 5, "-"
        gene2
                CDS
                        4, 6 "+"
                        6, 9, "+" 
                exon
                        1, 10, "+",
                        2, 5, "-"
name2 
...
...
```

My try :

```
import re

def read_dct(name):
        filename = name
        dct = {}
        ReadFH = open(filename, 'r')
        for i, line in enumerate(ReadFH):
                line = line.rstrip()
                tmp=re.split(r'\t', line)
                if(len(tmp) > 5):
                        dct[tmp[0]][tmp[1]][tmp2]=[tmp[3], tmp[4], tmp[5]]

        ReadFH.close
        return dct

filename = "file.txt"
dct = read_dct(filename)
print dct
```

I am getting problem while creating the dictionary :

```
dct[tmp[0]][tmp[1]][tmp2]=[tmp[3], tmp[4], tmp[5]]
```

Need help on this

Comment: Is it guaranteed that each `exon` or `CDS` will have 2 sets of 3 things?

Comment: no , they may have **multiple sets** and 3 things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) where values on third level are lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list)))

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        k1, k2, k3, *val = line.split()
        res[k1][k2][k3].append(val)

for k, v in res.items():
    for k2, v2 in v.items():
        for k3, v3 in v2.items():
            print('{}, {}, {}: {}'.format(k, k2, k3, v3))
```

Output:

```
name2, gene1, gene: [['1000', '1333', '+']]
name1, gene2, cds: [['4', '6', '+'], ['6', '9', '+']]
name1, gene2, exon: [['1', '10', '+'], ['2', '5', '-']
name1, gene1, cds: [['1', '2', '+'], ['2', '5', '-']]
name1, gene1, exon: [['1', '2', '+'], ['2', '5', '-']]
```

Above only works on Python 3 since [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) is not supported on Python 2. On Python 2 you can store the `list` returned by `split` and use slice to get the keys & value:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        l = line.split()
        k1, k2, k3 = l[:3]
        res[k1][k2][k3].append(l[3:])
```

Comment: Deleted my answer, because after fixing the error it would have been identical to yours. Might add the link to the [PEP about extended unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), though.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks for the link, added to the answer.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest changing "Above only works..." to "this and this only works...", since the rest of the approach, particularly the nested `defaultdict`, still works fine in Python 2. You'd just have to use `k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6 = ...` instead, or no unpacking at all.